# Infinite recursion while extending the admin's app change_form template

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates

I have the following template in `template/admin/change_form.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
  {% include "dojango/base.html" %}
  {% block dojango_content %}
  {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

However for some reason it throws a

```
TemplatesyntaxError: TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/cms/post/add/
Caught RuntimeError while rendering: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: I'm note sure you can extend change_form at that level? does it not have to be per app/model e.g. template/admin/cms/post/change_form.html

Comment: @Jameso: The documentation specifies otherwise

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know it's late, but...

If extending - which is a far better option than duplicating - the key is to have it named anything ***except*** `/admin/change_form.html`.

(Although the OP referred to `template/admin/change_form.html`, this is simply because a path in his TEMPLATE_DIRS tuple ends in '/template' - mine generally end in '/templates' - but, these directories can be named anything and located anywhere.)

It will be used automatically on a per-app basis if named `/admin/<MyAppName>/change_form.html`

It will be used automatically on a per-model basis if named `/admin/<MyAppName>/<MyModelName>/change_form.html`

It can be named anything if specified explicitly in the ModelAdmin

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'subdir/my_change_form.html'
```

Finally, if insistent on naming it  `/admin/change_form.html`, you can - provided that the `extends` tag contains the full path to your django installation instead of a relative one.

Comment: This is a much better answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You are in `admin/change_form.html` and you extend `admin/change_form.html`. You cannot extend the same template which you are in.

You probably expected that if you override template from admin application, you can extend the one you override. But this is not how it works. When you override a template you cannot access it.

Solution to your problem is to copy original template and change things you don't like.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can point your `AdminOptions` class to another template using the `change_form_template` property.

Something like:

```
class MyOptions(AdminOptions):
    change_form_template = 'myapp/my_change_form.html'
```

And `myapp/my_change_form.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solved by placing the overridden template under myapp/templates/admin/myapp instead of myapp/templates/admin.

Comment: Although the accepted answer works, it is a little heavy handed in my opinion. This is a better answer because, as the docs say, "it is usually neither necessary nor advisable to replace an entire template".

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this that I have found is to use `'..'` to go up a couple of directories, then go back down into directories that should only be found in the Django code base.

As the Django templates are in something like `"django/contrib/admin/templates/admin"`, I found that this worked me:

```
{% extends "../../admin/templates/admin/change_form.html" %}
```

If that still causes a clash with some other structure you have, you could go further:

```
{% extends "../../../contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html" %}
```

or even:

```
{% extends "../../../../django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html" %}
```

Although it is a little hacky, at least by doing the above you don't have to use some other technique that involves copying the django source or setting up a symlink.

Answer (score 0):

With Django core it's impossible. But it is not impossible.

Copy and paste "the original template and change things you don't like" it's very ugly.

**Don't make in the templates, whatever you don't make in python**

This solution is to any template:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-extends

Comment: You have to patch Django when you use DEBUG=True. This isn't pretty as well.

Comment: I have to patch Django when DEBUG = False. If you don't want use smart-extends, and you want a patch you can see this pull request: https://github.com/django/django/pull/217